# Overriding methods in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm trying to do something like this:

```
tabs.addTab(new Tab("Test1")
{
    public override void OnGUI()
    {   
       //My code here
    }
});
```

I have done this many times on java (override a function when creating the object) , but now i'm using Unity with C# , and i'm trying to find how to do it or its equivalent .

Thanks for reading , Any idea?

Comment: If `OnGUI()` is a method of `Tab` class - put `public override ...` in a `Tab` class itself, if you want providing custom logic for different Tab instances - inject delegate/lambda/

Comment: mmm , i understand the idea , ill try now thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if C# allows you to override methods when creating a new object, but you could use delegates instead.

A delegate is a variable that stores a function for its value. Something like this should do more or less what you are looking for

```
class Tab
{
    public delagate void MyOnGUI(); // Declare the delegate

    private MyOnGUI onGUI;  // An instance of the delegate

    public Tab(string s, MyOnGUI onGUI)
    {
        this.onGUI = onGUI;
        //...
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        onGUI(); // Call the delegate
    }
}
// ...

tabs.addTab(new Tab("test", delegate(){
    // Your code here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to override a method when initializing a new object in c#. In order to do this, you should first inherit the tab class then override OnGUI method assuming that this method is not declared as private etc.

```
public class MyTab : Tab
{
    public override void OnGUI()
    {
        //My code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public virtual void Update(){} in base and Run it as base.Update();